# Trigonometry graph question.

Tags: trigonometry

(a) Sketch the graph of $\tan x$ for values of $x$ between $0$ and $360$.
(b) Solve the equation : $\cot x = 0.15$

for values of $x$ between $0$ and $360$.
Express your answer(s) in degrees.

(c) Evaluate $cosec x$ if $\cot x = 0.15$.

Comment: The graph of $\tan(x)$ should be in your book...

Comment: I understand the graph of tan, just thought I should post the question holistically if say cot x = 0.15 is linked to the graph.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome. I understand that cot = 1/tan and cosec = 1/sin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part b:

$\cot(\theta) = 0.15$

$\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)} = 0.15$

$0.15 \tan(\theta) = 1$

$\frac{1}{0.15} = \tan(\theta)$

$20/3 = \tan(\theta)$

$\arctan(20/3) = \theta$

$\theta = 81.46923439$

Part c:

$\csc(81.46923439) = ?$

Try and figure this one on your own

Comment: Thanks Louie, understood the answer (except the arctan stuff but I'm able to complete my equations without it whilst using the sine inverse). However, I'm not quite sure what step to take for the csc part. Hit cosine and then divide it by one?

Comment: A few things. If tan(x)=y then arctan(y)=x. It is an inverse function. Think of it like this: if ab = c, then b = c/a. It is just the inverse operation, but it takes a while to get used to. Just remember this: if tan(x) = y then arctan(y) = x.

Comment: Also csc(81.469...) = 1 / sin(81.469...)